# Using a List of Objects in ListView c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm having some difficulty getting a list of objects using a list view.

What I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

[OBJECT ONE IMAGE ARRAY HERE]

[OBJECT TWO IMAGE ARRAY HERE]

[OBJECT THREE IMAGE ARRAY HERE]

And so on until its gone through the whole list.

However the difficulty im running into is,

Its ignoring the 'Image2' in each object.

I can't imagine why it would completely ignore an image like that.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="Grid">
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="680" Margin="-0,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="1024">
            <ListView x:Name="listage" ItemsSource="{Binding Set}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView x:Name="listage2" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,100,0,0">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image1}"></Image>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image2}"></Image>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Image3}"></Image>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"></WrapPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"></WrapPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>

        </WrapPanel>

    </Grid>
```

My Constructor is as follows (this is a test atm so thats why its kinda messy :P)

```
    list.Add(new ChampionSetDisplay(@"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\1001.png", @"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\1006,png", @"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\1058.png"));
    list.Add(new ChampionSetDisplay(@"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\1057.png", @"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\2003,png", @"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\1055.png"));
    list.Add(new ChampionSetDisplay(@"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\1076.png", @"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\3009,png", @"C:\Program Files\ItemSetManager\Assets\Items\3008.png"));
    Set = new ObservableCollection<List<ChampionSetDisplay>>();
    Set.Add(list);
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
    listage.DataContext = this;
```

And finally, my ChampionSetDisplay Object

```
   public String Image1 { get; set; }
    public String Image2 { get; set; }
    public String Image3 { get; set; }

    public ChampionSetDisplay(String itemPath, String item2, String item3) 
    {
        Image1 = itemPath;
        Image2 = item2;
        Image3 = item3;
    }
```

I would appreciate any and all help with this, thank you.

If you need any more information feel free to ask.

Comment: first thing I would check is to make sure that you have the path to the image correctly defined are Image 1 and Image 3 displaying and or populating correctly..?

Comment: Yes All the images in that fill Image2 are correct paths, First thing I checked.

Comment: Try giving each image a fixed width and height. Or try replacing them with Rectangles - what happens?

Comment: As hardcoded rectangles with different BG's it works. all 3 display.

Comment: LOL. Go hide your head in shame :)

Answer (score 1):

Yup.... ,'s aren't .'s for file extensions! Just a typo that was very annoying to miss because it was in a string GAH.